# Why is inline CSS added to images automatically?

Tags: images, css

I have placed images on Wordpress page templates without any inline style attribute but it seem Wordpress automatically add style tag with `width` and `height` set to zero.

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/ecoblog/images/hiw-image-1.png" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
```

Sometimes height is set to its original dimentsions and sometimes after complete refresh its values are zero.

What is causing this?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: @toscho no it is not happning anymore. Themes's JS file was doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you ask a question: maybe check on a other install of WP, is this the default? It is not? The problem is very often from plugins or themes. Disable plugins and switch to the default theme, current Twenty Twelve and check your problem.

The current release 3.5 and 3.4* have not this insert as default, only the img tag with path and alt attribute.

Comment: I can confirm, none of my installs do it either, whatevers doing it, it's not standard WP behavior

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was a problem with themes JS file which tries to maintain aspect ratio of images. Commenting it solves the issue.